# getting java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.Status cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaModelStatus while opening class file

Tags: eclipse-plugin, scala-ide

This happens with scala ide 4.3.0

I am getting below error while opening class file from maven dependencies jar using eclipse decompiler plugin.

> HINT: I am trying to open compiled jar from of a Scala project.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.Status cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaModelStatus
```

Error details

```
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0-vfinal-2015-12-01T15:55:22Z-Typesafe
java.version=1.8.0_102
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor


Editor could not be initialized.
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.Status cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaModelStatus
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClassFile.getBuffer(ClassFile.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClassFile.getSource(ClassFile.java:509)
    at org.sf.feeling.decompiler.editor.JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.doOpenBuffer(JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.java:99)
    at org.sf.feeling.decompiler.editor.JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.doOpenBuffer(JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.java:81)
    at org.sf.feeling.decompiler.editor.JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.doOpenBuffer(JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.java:71)
    at org.sf.feeling.decompiler.editor.JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.doSetInput(JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3220)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$13.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2157)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3238)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3265)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:305)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor109.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:983)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4734)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:705)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1145)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$23(WorkbenchPage.java:3125)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$9.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3107)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3102)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3066)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3056)
    at org.sf.feeling.decompiler.actions.OpenClassWithContributionFactory$OpenClassesAction.run(OpenClassWithContributionFactory.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest link reference about this issue is at [refer here](https://app.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1002064-java-lang-classcastexception--org-eclipse-core-runtime-status-cannot-be-cast-to-org-eclipse-jdt-c---/details)

it may be due to this comments

*It looks like a problem with the JDT aspects. It is likely due to a slight change in the internals of JDT between 3.x and 4.x.*